# Inner join multiple ms access database

Tags: php, ms-access, inner-join

The code I have below is to get data from one access database. How can I do in order to get data from **TWO** access database in PHP? And using INNER JOIN? I have tried a few codes but it doesn't seems to be working. Please help me thank you.

```
$filename="data.mdb";
$link = "C:/database/".$filename;
$conn_access = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$link", "", "");
if (!$conn_access) { die('Database cant connect : file not found! '); }


$a = "SELECT * from table1";
$resulta=odbc_exec($conn_access,$a); 
if (!$resultsql) { die('Query failed123');} 

while (odbc_fetch_row($resulta)){
   $date = odbc_result($resultsql,"date"); 
   $time = odbc_result($resultsql,"time");
}
```

Comment: For possible Access SQL syntax for referring to external database, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076622/access-sql-query-from-another-db.  That answer is of course not specific to PHP or ODBC, but I think it will work.

Comment: An alternative would be in one database to add linked tables which could then be referenced in the SQL without any special syntax.

Comment: Also see https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/import-or-link-to-data-in-another-access-database-095ab408-89c7-45b3-aac2-58036e45fcf6.  I don't have a PHP environment setup, so I cannot test all of this.  I suggest after testingand hopefully finding a solution, that you post an answer to your own question.  Not only will that become a good reference, but you'll can get benefit from upvotes, etc.