# Access SQL FROM IN and JOINS

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, select

I've been successfully using

```
SELECT [field] FROM [Table] IN 'Network Location';
```

this question filled me in on that
[Access SQL Query from another DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076622/access-sql-query-from-another-db)

My question is: How does a JOIN fit into this framework

Is it

```
SELECT [field] 
FROM [Table] IN 'Network Location' 
JOIN [Table2] 
  ON [Table2].field = [Table].field;
```

or

```
SELECT [field]
FROM [Table] 
JOIN [Table2] 
  ON [Table2].field = [Table].field IN 'Network Location' ;
```

it feels like the former is the correct one. SQL statements are supposed to be like sentences and that one feels most appropriately ordered.

Comment: Are you in any position to try out both versions and see which one works?

Comment: The answer may be neither version, [see this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25571112/ms-access-join-tables-in-separate-databases).

Comment: I have to create new separate databases to do the testing which wouldn't be a problem. From what you posted there it looks like the IN clause just needs to follow whichever table is external. which makes sense. and from further answers you can get real complicated by putting a bunch of location/password informaiton into the brackets where the table name would be.

Comment: Tested and yeah my versions dont work. the FROM IN only seems to work when its the only table being referenced

Comment: "SQL statements are supposed to be like sentences"--Whatever that is supposed to mean & however it could possibly supposedly help, it is a dead end. Ditto for "feels". Read the manual. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the bracketed or backticked name qualifier to query from external Access databases. Semantically, this would follow other RBDMS' (e.g., Oracle, Postgres, SQL Server, MySQL, SQLite) period qualifiers to query across clusters, schemas, databases on same machine/server. From there use table aliases for referencing in `SELECT`, `JOIN`, `WHERE`, and other clauses.

```
SELECT t1.[field] 
FROM [C:\Path\To\External\myDatabase.accdb].[Table] t1
INNER JOIN [Table2] t2
  ON t2.field = t1.field;

SELECT t1.`field` 
FROM `C:\Path\To\External\myDatabase.accdb`.`Table` t1
INNER JOIN `Table2` t2
  ON t2.field = t1.field;
```

Do note, Access requires `JOIN` to be specific: `INNER`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT`.

---

And thanks to the JET/ACE SQL engine, you can even query Excel workbooks and CSV files in similar manner assuming data is contiguous in a table-like range:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=C:\Path\To\myWorkbook.xlsx].[SheetName$] AS t;

SELECT t.*
FROM [text;database=C:\Path\To\Folder].myFile.csv AS t;
```

Comment: yeah i just tested my versions. it only seems to work if its the only table being referenced. your method works great, thank you

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help!