# MS Access SQL Deleting record based on external table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, sql-delete

I had a similar question regarding selecting records based on an external table (in an unlinked table):
[Access SQL FROM IN and JOINS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57167374/access-sql-from-in-and-joins/57169149?noredirect=1#comment100852957_57169149)

This time I'm trying to **delete** records in an *internal* table based on criteria in an *external* one.

```vb
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Dim SQLstring As String
    SQLstring = "Delete * FROM Testtable1 AS tnf WHERE ([Network Location].[Testtable2].[Customers] = tnf.[Customers]) AND ([Network Location].[Testtable2].[Contract] = '2003') Or ([Network Location].[Testtable2].[Active]='N');"
    DoCmd.RunSQL (SQLstring)
End Sub
```

Its telling me that `"` is not a valid name and to check if theres invalid characters or punctuation or if its too long. I cant find anything that talks about SQL lengths but i'm pretty sure this isn't too long.

Is there something I'm missing about my SQl statement I've gone through it over and over and I'm not seeing an issue.

Should the `WHERE` clause have an `Exists (Select)` clause?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a `delete` query can only delete records from one table at a time, only one dataset can be referenced in the `from` clause. With your current query, you would need to reference `testtable2` within the `from` clause, which would result in an invalid `delete` query.

As such, you'll instead need to use `where exists` with a subquery, e.g.:

```sql
delete from testtable1 as t1
where exists 
(
    select 1 from [Network Location].[Testtable2] t2 
    where t2.customers = t1.customers and (t2.contract = '2003' or t2.active = 'N')
)
```

I've also surrounded the `or` expression with parentheses, as I assume that it is the desired logic to delete records with a matching `customers` record and either of the other two conditions, rather than deleting *any* record for which `t2.active = 'N'` (since `and` has operator precedence over `or`).

Comment: Was just testing an Exists clause. thank you for adding this.
whats the difference between putting a `Select 1` vs `Select [field]` cause the 1 worked appropriately?

Comment: `select 1` is purely used for optimisation, since we only care that the query contains records, we are not interested in the data returned by such records.

Comment: I didnt know that. I'm gonna write that into my cheat sheet. thank you